# No such file or directory: 'train_art_path'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to read documents from a file path using a Jupyter Notebook as follows.

```
train_art_path = "/work/TEXT_SUMMARIZATION/train_dialogue.txt"
with open(train_art_path, 'r') as file:
    a=file.readlines()
    print(a)
    print('\n')
```

I get the following issue:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_79659/545421924.py in <module>
----> 1 with open(train_art_path, 'r') as file:
      2     a=file.readlines()
      3     print(a)
      4     print('\n')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'train_art_path'
```

Alternatively, I tried to read documents as follows. It works perfectly.

```
with open('train_dialogue.txt', 'r') as file:
    a=file.readlines()
    print(a)
    print('\n')
```

Can you please help me to solve the first one? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `train_art_path` as a variable, so should not have quotes `'` after assignment. Change...

```
with open('train_art_path', 'r') as file:
```

to

```
with open(train_art_path, 'r') as file:
```

Comment: Hi @Redox thanks, I tried without quotes. But, I get the same error as mentioned above. I too updated the question.

Comment: From path, looks like you are in UNIX. Are you sure the path is correct?  Is the `work` folder under root - `/`  or in current dir? Try `cat  /work/TEXT_SUMMARIZATION/train_dialogue.txt`. If this is under your current working directory, you will need to add a `.` before the `/`. Let me know\

Comment: Thanks, It works using the current working directory